# mysql delete row when user exits

Tags: mysql

i am in a situation where i want the db to delete a row when the user exits the application. even in the middle of the application. how can it be done?

to be more specific, consider a survey of 10 questions. i am storing the user's selections in a DB. now suppose the user exits at the 5th question. i want to delete the user's records then and there. so that if the user wishes to start again. s/he can start afresh.

Comment: What language you're trying to do it in?

Comment: Is the database local or remote? What if your application crashes, for example due to a power surge? Maybe it would be better to clean up on application start-up rather than (or as well as) shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to rethink your design. You should start a new session each time the user starts the survey. Clean up abandoned answers on a scheduled basis.

Never depend on browser close to perform actions like this.

Comment: I would even dare to say to store the survey progress in a session and save it in the database on finish

Answer (score 0):

You need a watchdog function that is called regularly.  It compares it's list of logged in users with the real list.  When there is a conflict it performs the SQL operation you require.